# Create Thread for each SQL query record

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm new to C# and am looking to spin up a thread for each record returned from a database query.

At present I have this following method:

```
myEntities getUsers = new myEntities();
var query = from userTable in getUsers.userTable
                    select userTable;

// FOR EACH USER CREATE NEW USER INSTANCE
foreach (userTable account in query)
{
    User u = new User(account.userName, account.password);
}
```

What my goal is, is for each record to create a thread and inside that thread then call the User method.

I know that there's `System.Threading` namespace that I should use and then to spin up a new thread to use

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(<WHAT GOES IN HERE>)); 
thread.Start();
```

What should be getting passed in the `ThreadStart` part?

Comment: I'm trying to think of scenarios where this would be a good idea, and I'm coming up short... yeah, I really don't think this is a good idea. If there are enough records for it to be worth parallelizing them, then you already *don't want that many threads*. `Parallel.ForEach` might be an option, as that is at least keeping the number of threads sane.

Answer (score 4):

The most straight forward solution is to use the Parallel LINQ method `Parallel.ForEach`.

```
myEntities getUsers = new myEntities ();
var query = from userTable in getUsers.userTable
                    select userTable;

// FOR EACH LOGIN CREATE NEW TRADER INSTANCE
Parallel.ForEach(query, user =>
{
    User u = new User(account.userName, account.password);

    // call your method here!
});
```

From MSDN:

> Executes a foreach (For Each in Visual Basic) operation on an
>   IEnumerable in which iterations may run in parallel.
>
> The body delegate is invoked once for each element in the source enumerable. It is provided with the current element as a parameter.
>
> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992001(v=vs.110).aspx

Not that each operation **may** be run on another thread. Some elements may have their handler executed on the same thread. The `Task` framework will optimize for best throughput based on the target system. You may require more control.

Comment: Parallels is the right answer - Automatically assign maximum parallels thread and partitions size. Upvote!

Comment: If I'm setting global variables will they still be specific to each record or is there a chance that they will cross over?

Comment: @CPB07 I wouldn't recommend it. They are likely to collide.

Comment: @Gusdor so then I'd be better creating threads for each account as most of the time there is going to be simultaneous calls made to the same methods, whilst at the same time I'd be better also using global variables so they can be accessed class-wide as opposed to having to pass them back and forth as parameters?

Comment: @CPB07 you are almost always better off avoiding 'globals' of any kind. If everything is global, you can only do one operation at a time. In C# that will be anything marked `static` - C# doesn't have true globals.

Answer (score 1):

In general terms, the easiest trick here is an anonymous method, for example:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() => u.DoSomething("abc", 123));
```

But  as per my comment - this is almost certainly a bad idea and not what you should actually do. "Thread  per user" is - by itself - enough to make me wince.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and probably the best option would be Parallel.ForEach.

```
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        myEntities getUsers = new myEntities ();
        var query = from userTable in getUsers.userTable
                            select userTable;

        Parallel.ForEach(query, CreateUser);
    }

    private void CreateUser(userTable account)
    {
        new User(account.userName, account.password);
    }
```